# Validation loss for pytorch Faster-RCNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I’m currently doing object detection on a custom dataset using transfer learning from a pytorch pretrained Faster-RCNN model (like in torchvision [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html)).
I would like to compute validation loss dict (as in train mode)  at the end of each epoch.
I can just run model in train mode for validation like this:

```
model.train()
for images, targets in data_loader_val:
    images = [image.to(device) for image in images]
    targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

    with torch.no_grad():
         val_loss_dict = model(images, targets)
         print(val_loss_dict)
```

but I don't think, that it's "correct" way to validate (cause some special layers like dropout and batch norm works different in eval/train mode). And in eval mode model returns predicted bboxes (as expected).  Can I use some build-in function for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't seem to quite understand the question, but what speaks against `model.eval()`?

Comment: @marhoruf Calling `model.eval()` disables dropout and changes batch norm to use historical statistics, call it before validation. Similarly `model.train()` should be called before training. By default modules are in train mode.

Comment: This is a valid issue. While both losses and outputs are always calculated, currently torchvision returns losses *onyl* in training mode, see this line: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/4cbe71401fc6e330e4c4fb40d47e814911e63399/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L38

Answer (score 6):

There was some discussion about this issue [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/compute-validation-loss-for-faster-rcnn/62333). The conclusion there is that it is absolutely valid to calculate validation loss in train mode. The numerical value of the val loss in itself is not meaningful, **only the trend is important** to prevent overfitting. Therefore while train mode does alter the numerical value of the loss, it's still valid to use.

---

There is however another issue with efficiency here, in case you also need the model outputs in the validation process (for calculating IoU, accuracy, etc. as is often the case). Right now RCNN in torchvision gives you either losses or outputs, depending on training/eval mode.

**UPDATE:**
I realized this fix is not working unfortunately. All submodules would have to be patched to calculate both losses and outputs. Too bad.

> My dirty solution was patching the `GeneralizedRCNN` class from which
> `FasterRCNN` inherits. The problem is in
> [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/4cbe71401fc6e330e4c4fb40d47e814911e63399/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L38)
> line, in `eager_outputs()`. The workaround:
>
> ```
>     return losses, detections
>
> model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn() model.eager_outputs =
> eager_outputs_patch
> ```
>
> Now you can get both outputs after a single inference run: `model.train() with torch.no_grad(): loss_dict, outputs = model(images, targets). # yaay, now we have both!` Note that you still need to put your model to train mode in
> order to have the losses too. In eval mode `GeneralizedRCNN`'s
> submodules (rpn, roi_heads) don't calculate any loss, and `loss_dict`
> is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by editing Generalized RCNN, RPN, roi_heads. Just add an if-statement to handle when targets are passed to still calculate loss even if not in training mode. For example in RPN:

```
losses = {}
    if self.training:
        assert targets is not None
        labels, matched_gt_boxes = self.assign_targets_to_anchors(anchors, targets)
        regression_targets = self.box_coder.encode(matched_gt_boxes, anchors)
        loss_objectness, loss_rpn_box_reg = self.compute_loss(
            objectness, pred_bbox_deltas, labels, regression_targets)
        losses = {
            "loss_objectness": loss_objectness,
            "loss_rpn_box_reg": loss_rpn_box_reg,
        }
    else:
        if targets is not None:
            labels, matched_gt_boxes = self.assign_targets_to_anchors(anchors, targets)
            regression_targets = self.box_coder.encode(matched_gt_boxes, anchors)
            loss_objectness, loss_rpn_box_reg = self.compute_loss(
                objectness, pred_bbox_deltas, labels, regression_targets)
            losses = {
                "loss_objectness": loss_objectness,
                "loss_rpn_box_reg": loss_rpn_box_reg,
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete @mkisantal and @Colin Axel's answers, here is the complete list of modifications you need to do in Pytorch's Faster-RCNN code to get the following behaviors :

- in training, ie when network.train() and targets are provided, produce losses and output,
- in validation, ie when network.eval() and targets are provided, produce losses and output,
- in inference, ie when network.eval() and no targets are provided, produce output.

Tested today, with torchvision 0.12.

In `generalized_rcnn.py` (all files are in `torchvision/models/detection/`) :
Replace

```
if torch.jit.is_scripting():
        if not self._has_warned:
            warnings.warn("RCNN always returns a (Losses, Detections) tuple in scripting")
            self._has_warned = True
        return losses, detections
    else:
        return self.eager_outputs(losses, detections)
```

by

```
return losses, detections
```

In `rpn.py` :
Replace

```
if self.training:
        assert targets is not None
        labels, matched_gt_boxes = self.assign_targets_to_anchors(anchors, targets)
        regression_targets = self.box_coder.encode(matched_gt_boxes, anchors)
        loss_objectness, loss_rpn_box_reg = self.compute_loss(
            objectness, pred_bbox_deltas, labels, regression_targets
        )
        losses = {
            "loss_objectness": loss_objectness,
            "loss_rpn_box_reg": loss_rpn_box_reg,
        }
```

by

```
if targets is not None:
    labels, matched_gt_boxes = self.assign_targets_to_anchors(anchors, targets)
    regression_targets = self.box_coder.encode(matched_gt_boxes, anchors)
    loss_objectness, loss_rpn_box_reg = self.compute_loss(
    objectness, pred_bbox_deltas, labels, regression_targets)
    losses = {
      "loss_objectness": loss_objectness,
      "loss_rpn_box_reg": loss_rpn_box_reg,
     }
```

In `roi_heads.py` :
Replace

```
 if self.training:
    proposals, matched_idxs, labels, regression_targets = self.select_training_samples(proposals, targets)
else:
    labels = None
    regression_targets = None
    matched_idxs = None
```

by

```
if targets is not None:
    proposals, matched_idxs, labels, regression_targets = self.select_training_samples(proposals, targets)
else:
    labels = None
    regression_targets = None
    matched_idxs = None
```

and replace

```
if self.training:
        assert labels is not None and regression_targets is not None
        loss_classifier, loss_box_reg = fastrcnn_loss(class_logits, box_regression, labels, regression_targets)
        losses = {"loss_classifier": loss_classifier, "loss_box_reg": loss_box_reg}
else:
        boxes, scores, labels = self.postprocess_detections(class_logits, box_regression, proposals, image_shapes)
        num_images = len(boxes)
        for i in range(num_images):
            result.append(
                {
                    "boxes": boxes[i],
                    "labels": labels[i],
                    "scores": scores[i],
                }
            )
```

by

```
if labels is not None and regression_targets is not None:
    loss_classifier, loss_box_reg = fastrcnn_loss(class_logits, box_regression, labels, regression_targets)
    losses = {"loss_classifier": loss_classifier, "loss_box_reg": loss_box_reg}
boxes, scores, labels = self.postprocess_detections(class_logits, box_regression, proposals, image_shapes)
num_images = len(boxes)
for i in range(num_images):
result.append(
           {
             "boxes": boxes[i],
             "labels": labels[i],
             "scores": scores[i],
            }
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recognized that with the change:

```
if targets is not None:
proposals, matched_idxs, labels, regression_targets = self.select_training_samples(proposals, targets)
```

The result change (I get a much higher mAP with it), so I think thats not a valid change.